# Discord bot only works for a minute or so after deploying from heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I made a super-simple discord bot and I am using Heroku to deploy it. After each deploy, the bot works for a couple of minutes and then goes silent. I'm using discord.js, and here's [my git repo](https://github.com/vityavv/victors-random-bot).

It would be helpful if there was a solution not using Heroku CLI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the bot crashing have you looked up the heroku log?

Comment: @LucasRosenberger is there a way to see heroku logs without the cli interface?

Comment: honestly i do not have much experience with heroku i only know that it works fine via cli.

Comment: You can see the logs on heroku.com. You can find the link under the More menu (upper right) on the app's dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was deploying my discord bot with the web process, so Heroku automatically crashed it after it didn't bind itself to port in 60 seconds.

Thanks to Lucas Rosenbreger and MikaS for helping me see the logs.